# How do you "If post page is greater than page 1 show code" on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my blog post broken down to page breaks, and I only want ads to show up on every page, except page 1. I've seen someone do it, i just cant seem to find it.

```
if(page > 1) {

 <p>Show this this line of code here</p>
}
```

i remeber it looking something like that

Answer (score 0):

The page number of a multi-page blog post is stored in the global variable `$page`. Retrieve that variable for use in your code.

Example:

```
global $page;

if ( $page > 1 ) {

    // output here.

}
```

Comment: I got the idea by "broken down to page breaks" he meant it was paginated? lol, one of us is likely right :)

Comment: @RickCalder That's a good point, the OP may be referring to an archive rather than a single post.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this should do it.

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', $default )

If( $paged > 1 ) {
  echo '<p>Show this line of code</p>';
}
```